# extra 'field_' prepended to fieldnames in views $rows (Drupal 7)

Tags: 7, views, theming

I created a field "myfield".  I then created a Drupal 7 view and selected the field 'field_myfield'.  (As expected the system prepended 'field_' to my fieldname.)  When I call `dsm ($rows)` to look at the row data that gets passed to my custom template, I see that the field is now called 'field_field_myfield'.  Why is a second 'field_' prepended to the fieldname?  Should I assume all fieldnames in $rows will have 'field_field_' prepended?

Answer (score 0):

The drupal field api enters fields in the database with the `field_` prefix (to avoid conflicts with other existing tables). If you use field in your name as well, it will become `field_field_...` in the database.

And since views loads the fields directly from the database, the prefix is there as well.

Comment: I see now that my question was not clear enough.  I called my field "myfield" and by the time it shows up in my template, it is called "field_field_myfield".  I have updated the question.  I hope it is now clearer.  Thanks.

Comment: Views has its own way of naming fields which can be confusing. Basically what you are passing to dsm() is an object constructed from a query where the individual data members are the aliases of the data items. These typically relate to the original field names but they generally have additional prefix strings added.

Comment: Thanks Alfred.  That answers my question.  Do you know whether views has any api functions that would allow me to access the row-data, using the original (not aliased) fieldnames?  Also, if you wouldn't mind, please create a separate post for your response (rather than a comment) so that I can mark your answer as 'accepted'.  Thanks very much.